# plot with for loop

Tags: r

I have a data set of stream temp over time. The time field is %d/%m/%y %H:%M. I would like to create a plot of the temperature through time by unique dates. For each day there are about 15 measurements taken every 15min. How do I create a for loop to do this? Here is what I have but it doesn't work... I can't seem to figure out how to tell it to pick a unique date.

```
airdate <- as.POSIXct(airtemp$datetime, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
for (i in 1:length(airdate)) {
  plot(x=airdate, y=airtemp$value, type="l")
   }
```

Comment: If you want a unique date (i.e. day, not time), which one of many measurements from that day will you plot?

Comment: If your `airtemp$datetime` and `airtemp$value` are the same length you can simply `plot()` them without using a loop, with the x-axis off. Then you can use `mtext()` or `axis()` to put the date on the x-axis.

Comment: I have to use a for loop because this is an assignment for a class that asks us to fit one in... For the unique day I want to plot the value over the 24 hour period of the day. I would like the results to be separate plots for each day, each plot showing their value through the 24 hour period.... I am new to R so I could be completely off. Also, the datetime column has the date and time in that single column. I could go separate those into two columns.